# C# MySQL throws an exception when run on a server

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm currently creating a Console application which has to run with out any interaction. During this application I'm connecting to a MySQL server to check the last updated data. This runs without a problem on my work station, even from a network drive.

However, whenever I put it onto our server and let it run it for me it suddenly can't run the MySQL. It fails on connection.Open();

I'm currently using:
-MySQL connector version 6.8.8
-.NET Framework 4.5.2

Here's the error it throws;

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GetLocationEvidence(SafePEFileHandle peFile, SecurityZone& zone, StringHandleOnStack retUrl)
   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateLocationEvidence()
   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
   at System.Security.Policy.AssemblyEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GenerateHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean hostCanGenerate)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean markDelayEvaluatedEvidenceUsed)
   at System.Security.Policy.AppDomainEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GenerateHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean hostCanGenerate)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.RawEvidenceEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.EvidenceEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetEvidenceInfo(AppDomain appDomain, String exePath, String& typeName)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetTypeAndHashSuffix(AppDomain appDomain, String exePath)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.RequireCompleteInit(IInternalConfigRecord record)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration.get_Settings()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager.IsReplicationGroup(String groupName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at WarningTextSolution.MyDB.OpenConnection()
```

And relevant code:

```
MySqlConnection con;
public MyDB()
    {
        logger = actionlogger;
        logger.Log("------ [ STARTING MySQL ] -----");
        logger.Log("Attempting to create MySQL database connection");
        try
        {
            string connectionString = "server=SERVERIP;uid=USERID;pwd=PASSWORD;database=DATABASE;";
            con = new MySqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            logger.Log("Connection accepted");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            logger.Log("MySQL exception: " + e);
            Console.WriteLine("Error occured, please read the log.");
        }
        logger.Log("------ [ MySQL STARTED ] -----");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Opens a connection to ecommerce Database
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True if successful else false</returns>
    private bool OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            logger.Log("Attempting to open connection to server");
            con.Open();
            logger.Log("Connection successfully opened");
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.Log("Attempt failed");
            logger.Log("MySQL connection error: " + e);
            Console.WriteLine("MySQL error: " + e);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I've tried googling this and I haven't found any answer to this issue.

I've tried to Enable Native code debugging and enable SQL Server debugging, none of these has helped.

Should you need any more information, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: So, what has the replicatormanager got to do with your code? what do you do with it?

Comment: Nothing directly. It's called whenever I call the method Open() in the class MySqlConnection.

Comment: Are you sure the machine / user is allowed to access your database? I think mysql can throw a TypeInitializationException when it is not the case.

Comment: Yeah, it's allowed to access the database.

Comment: Post your code, including the connection string. Also check your production server uses replication. It's impossible to guess what's wrong with the code  without actually seeing it

Comment: *SQL Server* debugging has nothing to do with *MySQL*, they are different products. Native debugging is irrelevant too - the error is a *client* error. If you google for this error message you'll find many similar cases. Typically, the problem is caused by missing DLL files

Comment: I've added relevant code regarding the MySQL. I know I haven't forgotten the DLL file, because I tried removing it and it gave me a different error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I wasn't properbly informed regarding our server (Or I forgot this detail), the user logged in on our production server does not have the same rights as my user account has and this result in the MySQL error I recieved.

Comment: The missing permissions were simple Read/Write.